# How to % encode single quotes when making jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding

I am using $.ajax to send a SQL query to my web server. The query string contains several single quotes ('). I encountered a very messy problem on encoding single quotes.

My code like this, please note the single quotes in query string:

```
var query = "select SID, age from Students where Name=\'Jason\'" + String.fromCharCode(10) +
            "order by age asc";
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mywebserver/query",
    data: {
        env: "dbserver1",
        endTime: "getUTCDate()",
        startTime: "dateadd(hour, -336, getUTCDate())",
        text: query
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (datum) {
});
```

If I don't explicitly call encodeURIComponent before make AJAX call, jQuery will encode it for me, however, the single quotes are not encoded to %27 by default, so query doesn't work;

If I pass an encoded query string to jQuery, it will encode again, that messes up the query string.

The only solution i can imagine is, i have to overwrite the behavior how jQuery encodes URL, and replace all (') with %27. But I don't know if jQuery supports that. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `GET`, you can "override" this behaviour of jQuery by creating your own query string...

```
url: "http://mywebserver/query"+
        "?env=" + encodeURIComponent(dbserver1)+
        "&endTime="+encodeURIComponent(getUTCDate())+
        "&startTime="+encodeURIComponent(dateadd(hour, -336, getUTCDate()))+
        "&text="+encodeURIComponent(query)
```

This is equivalent to what you're doing